# Creating a table using a for loop in code behind

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, for-loop, listitem

I am currently using two content placeholders to display the title and summary of list items. Currenlty I am only showing the title and summary for 2 list items. Instead of using the placeholders I want to be able to created a table in code behind that generates rows and cells which display the title and summary of as many list items as it is specified in a for loop. The code below shows waht I currenlty have in terms of creating the table in code beheind but havent quite figured out how to wire it into the for loop I currently have to display list items:

```
//for loop to iterate through the list retrieving the required amount of lits items
//the number of times to iteratie through the loop will be specified by the user using 
//the custom property
if (this.WebPart != null & this.WebPart.ListName != null & 
!this.WebPart.OverviewArticle)
{
string Listname = this.WebPart.ListName; //get the value of the ListName custom 
property
int publicationNumberofitems = this.WebPart.pubNumOfItems; //get the value of the 
                                                           //pubNumOfItems as int

//since the first iten in the list is 0 (making this variable -1 cause the correct 
//amount of details to be displayed based on the number
//provided via the pubNumOfItems custom property. So if a value of 2 is provided then 
//only two items will be displayed and so on.
int listItemsNumber = publicationNumberofitems - 1;

SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
SPList list = web.Lists[Listname];

SPListItemCollection collListItems = list.Items;

//creating a table to hold the list items in the for loop. This will replace the use 
//of the placeholders
Table table1 = new Table();
TableRow tr = new TableRow();
TableCell tc = new TableCell();



//for loop to iterate through the list retrieving the required amount of lits items
//the number of times to iteratie through the loop will be specified by the user using 
//the custom property
for (int i = 0; i < listItemsNumber && i < collListItems.Count; i++)
{
SPListItem listItems = collListItems[i];

string title1 = (string)collListItems[i]["Title"];
string summary1 = (string)collListItems[i]["Summary"];

//generating the table rows and cell is not currenlty working               
tr.Cells.Add(tc);
tc.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(title1));

//placeholders are no longer required, a table with rows and cells generated by the 
//for loop is required instead
//plhPubTitleHyper.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(title1));
//plhPubSummary.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(summary1));

}

}
```

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

UPDATED CODE:

```
//creating a table to hold the list items in the for loop. This will replace the use  
//of the placeholders
Table table1 = new Table();
TableRow tr = null;

//for loop to iterate through the list retrieving the required amount of lits items
//the number of times to iteratie through the loop will be specified by the user using 
//the custom property
for (int i = 0; i < listItemsNumber && i < collListItems.Count; i++)
{
SPListItem listItems = collListItems[i];

string title1 = (string)collListItems[i]["Title"];
//string summary1 = (string)collListItems[i]["Summary"];


tr = new TableRow();

TableCell c1 = new TableCell();
TableCell c2 = new TableCell();

c1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(title1));
//c2.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(summary1));//This needs to be in another row

tr.Cells.Add(c1);
//tr.Cells.Add(c2);

table1.Rows.Add(tr);

//plhPubTitleHyper.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(table1));

//plhPubTitleHyper.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(title1));
//plhPubSummary.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(summary1));

}

plhPubTitleHyper.Controls.Add(table1);
}
```

The updated code works but I now need to be able to add rows and have the summary in a different row rather than in a column on the same row.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Table table1 = new Table();
    TableRow tr = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
       tr = new TableRow();

       //You can also do a loop for the cell
       TableCell c1 = new TableCell();
       TableCell c2 = new TableCell();
       TableCell c3 = new TableCell();

       c1.Text = "Cell One";
       c2.Text = "Cell Two";
       c3.Text = "Cell Three";

       tr.Cells.Add(c1);
       tr.Cells.Add(c2);
       tr.Cells.Add(c3);

       table1.Rows.Add(tr);
    }

    form1.Controls.Add(table1);
```